# Confusion in a Mathematics Symbol

Tags: notation, permutations, combinations

I fail to understand what a certain symbol means, please explain.

It is in my permutation and combination chapter and it is for arrangements of 7 digits where something repeats thrice and something repeats twice. So the answer is correct that I understand.

But what is this symbol doing? Please help

The symbol https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQHTu.jpg and the symbol in context   https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKDGY.jpg

Comment: Well, seeing as $\frac{7!}{3!2!}=420$, the symbol doesn't seem to be doing much.

Comment: yaa thats ok @Arthur but what does this symbol mean in maths ? And by the way i know that this is a symbol.

Comment: Did you copy this from a board? Perhaps the instructor or however wrote it just wanted to highlight something, like one underlines things.

Comment: @quid no i didnt copy it from the board. If you want i ll give u the exact text.

Comment: Yes please. Give the exact text. With some context.

Comment: @quid here you go - http://imgur.com/GA3GfEN

Comment: what do you make of it guys ??

Comment: Thanks. I included this link in the post too and added a tag. I have no idea what this should be.

Comment: Same thing for the second occurrence--it's 60, so the symbol must be some sort of parenthetical apparatus. If you look in the front matter of the text, you may see an explanation. Or, there could be a glossary of symbols.

Comment: @MPW there is no glossary of symbols in my book :(

Comment: It looks more like a way of highlighting an expression than an actual function (although the identity is an "actual function", it doesn't have much use in this context).

Comment: @user166748 You should ask your instructor for a clean answer, I don't think it's a standard symbol.

Comment: I some of you may right it might just be highlighting or maybe acting like a paranthesis. My instructor does not have much idea :p

Comment: What's the title and author (and ISBN?) of the text?